# How to add an event to grpc completion queue in C++?

Tags: c++, grpc

I am trying to implement an async GRPC server, where whenever the client makes a call it gets an indefinite stream of messages. I read through the official documentation. It doesn't cover the scenario where I want to keep the stream open for each RPC. This article - https://www.gresearch.co.uk/article/lessons-learnt-from-writing-asynchronous-streaming-grpc-services-in-c/
addresses the issue of keeping the stream open by basically putting the callback handler object in the completion queue again.

The article suggests:

```
if (HasData())
{
    responder_.Write(reply_, this);
}
else
{
    grpc::Alarm alarm;
    alarm.Set(completion_queue_, gpr_now(gpr_clock_type::GPR_CLOCK_REALTIME), this);
}
```

I tried using the Alarm object approach as suggested in this article but for some reason on the next `Next` function call on completion queue I get `ok` argument as false - `GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));`. As a result, I have to close the server and am unable to wait on a stream till further data is available.

I am able to receive data fine till the `else` case is not hit.

Could someone please help me identify what I might be doing wrong? I am unable to find much C++ resources on GRPC. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. When Alarm goes out of scope, it will generate a Cancel() causing you to get !ok in Next().
2. if you want to use this, you would need to put the Alarm into your class scope and trigger it:

```cpp
    std::unique_ptr<Alarm> alarm_;
```

```cpp
    alarm_.reset(new Alarm);
    alarm_->Set(cq_, grpc_timeout_seconds_to_deadline(10), this);
```

from the doc on Alarm::Set:

> Trigger an alarm instance on completion queue cq at the specified
> time.
>
> Once the alarm expires (at deadline) or it's cancelled (see Cancel),
> an event with tag tag will be added to cq. If the alarm expired, the
> event's success bit will be true, false otherwise (ie, upon
> cancellation).